# name 'turtle' is not defined on line 4 in main.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Sorry for dumb question, new to python.  I have the following code, running python 3.7:

```
from turtle import *
color('blue', 'red')
turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.pd()
begin_fill()
forward(55)
left(90)
forward(110)
```

When I click run, it says I have an error on line three and four, but I can't figure out what's wrong.  I tried searching everywhere but I can't find anything that helps me figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Is there a turtle class in the turtle module? You have imported everything from the module with the `*` so if the functions `goto()` and `pu()` are not within a turtle class you can call them directly

Comment: You imported the items inside the `turtle` module, but you didn't import the module itself.  But since you did import all the items, you should just be able to say `goto(0,0)` instead of `turtle.goto(0,0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a Turtle object to use it

```
from turtle import *

bob = Turtle()
color('blue', 'red')
bob.pu()
bob.goto(0,0)
bob.pd()
begin_fill()
forward(55)
left(90)
forward(110)
```

Comment: Use caution with `from turtle import *`--it adds [100+ functions to the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75477522/6243352), often leading to bugs and confusion. Consider `import turtle` and `turtle.Turtle()` or `from turtle import Turtle`, only importing what you need.