# How do I fix NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined. Did you mean: 'tuple'?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to move a turtle in Python but I'm getting:

```
NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined. Did you mean: 'tuple'?
```

Here's my code:

```
from turtle import*

x = input('what is you fav color?(in eng pls)')
y = input('what is your name?')
yx10 = y * 100
t = turtle()
t.pencolor(x)t.forward(yx10)done*
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNs0L.png)

Comment: `t = turtle()` I think you meant `t = Turtle()` instead (capital T).

Comment: Also, why are you multiplying a name by 100?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid `from turtle import *`. It pollutes the namespace with over 120 functions and generally leads to confusion between turtle's instance and functional APIs:

```py
print(len(globals())) # => 9
from turtle import *
print(len(globals())) # => 131
```

versus:

```py
print(len(globals())) # => 9
import turtle
print(len(globals())) # => 10
```

The extra module prefix is a bit more typing, but makes ownership much clearer, making the code more readable and helping mitigate bugs.

We can see the `turtle` module has a property `Turtle`, which can be called to create a turtle:

```py
import turtle

print(turtle.Turtle) # => <class 'turtle.Turtle'>
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

A common mistake is calling the returned instance `turtle`, overwriting the module:

```py
import turtle

print(turtle.Turtle) # => <class 'turtle.Turtle'>
turtle = turtle.Turtle() # wrong!
```

If you want to call your instance `turtle`, you can use:

```py
from turtle import Turtle  # only import what you need

print(Turtle) # => <class 'turtle.Turtle'>
turtle = Turtle() # OK but potentially confusing
```

If you're not sure what's available on a turtle object, feel free to check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) or use `dir`:

```py
import turtle

print(dir(turtle))

# or filter out private properties
print([x for x in dir(turtle) if not x.startswith("_")])
```

---

After getting this in order, the code has an issue (other than bad formatting I assume is an artifact of pasting into the editor):

```py
y = input('what is your name?')
yx10 = y * 100
print(type(yx10)) # => <class 'str'>
print(repr(yx10)) # => 'foofoofoofoofoofoofoo<...>'
```

You probably meant:

```py
distance = int(input('How far do you want to move? '))
distance *= 100
print(type(distance)) # => <class 'int'>
print(repr(distance)) # => 500
```

Error handling is left as an exercise, both for the string to integer conversion above as well as illegal color strings.

Lastly, don't forget to call `done()`, if that's not a copy-paste error, or the better `turtle.done()` after fixing your import. Without the parentheses, it's a no-op unless you're using it in another expression.